# list-style-type not displaying

Tags: css

I am trying to display disc in nested `ul` items but with no success. I am not familiar with this behaviour but suspect that it might have something to do with `relative` & `absolute` positions of lists:

```
<ul class='top'>
 <li><a>whatever</a>
  <ul class='sub'>
   <li><a>whatever sub</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>

ul.top{
 position: relative;
}
ul.sub{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 list-style-type: disc;
}
ul a{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 z-index: 9999;         
}

                }
```

[**COMPLETE JSFIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ntQT/)

Items appear just the way I want but my style `disc` is missing.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset? Your disc bullets show up fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/QCgQa/

Comment: Seems fine to me. They're both discs.

Comment: Working for me. What browser are you using? What version?

Comment: Use latest Chrome & Firefox. Please check JSFIDDLE of complete page in edited post above. Thanks

Comment: @j08691 I do use simple CSS reset but what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @daniel.tosaba - Depending on your reset, everything.

Comment: Found the problem, see my answer below. @j08691 is correct - it was the reset

Comment: @j08691 I do reset `list-style` to `none` but that is all, and even upon commenting that one out my problem is still there.

Comment: I found the problem. The HTML is very messy - gimme a minute.. (PS. you'd benefit if you could simplify the structure of HTML...)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: okay, I think you wanted to have the disc appearing in such menu..  then my solution is not good for that - just wanted to give you a simpler way of building menus with lists. sorry if I misled you with this.

---

I kinda give up, the HTML is making my head hurt :)

But the problem lies with the messy `position:relative/absolute` declarations plus the display:inline set somewhere on `<a>` tag..

[Here's how you should build your menu list - much simpler (example on JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/5Eupw/)

Comment: overflows are there for a reason. you don't have to define top,bottom for absolute if you like default values

Answer (score -1):

Here's the problem:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    list-style: none; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

list-style: none; is preventing the list symbol from being shown at all. Remove that, and it should work fine.